# Running a display-based program without calling sudo / not as root

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, xorg, xserver

I have an Ubuntu server that runs a program that uses the gpu. 
Till now, to run my program, I’ve been calling

- `export DISPLAY=:0`
- `export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0`

Which works, however, this requires me to run my application as root, since root owns that :0 file. Ultimately, my question is how to configure my system to avoid this?

Some background:

This server is currently configured to bring up lightdm at startup. lightdm in turn starts Xorg, with -auth /var/run/sddm/root/:0, such that `ps -aux` shows this as a process:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

While playing around, I’ve succeeded in configuring everything so I don’t need sudo by:

- calling `export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority`
- adding a cookie for :0 in my user’s .Xauthority file with 
  `mcookie|sed -e 's/^/add :0 . /'|xauth`
- stopping lightdm
- restarting Xorg with `-auth “$HOME/.Xauthority”`

This is all well and good, but not a deployable solution. So here are other concerns:

If Xorg is to be brought up at boot time, how to provide access to specific users? Or should it somehow be brought up when users log on? If I'll be doing everything from the command line, do I even need lightdm? What are my options here, and what's the best way?

Comment: For clarification: Do you want one single running instance of the application that can be accessed by multiple users? Or should rather get every user its own independent instance?

Comment: The latter - every user should be able to run its own instance (as long as the user is authorized by the system, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

An easy one ist to allow access to an already running X with xhost (But use of xhost is rather discouraged, using cookies is considered to be more secure):

```
xhost +SI:localuser:USERNAME
```

---

Another one is to extract the cookie name from `ps -aux` as you did and copy it to `~/.Xauthority`. Change ownership for `~/.Xauthority` to the user. Only the user should have rw-access (`chmod 600`).

---

Another possibility is to get a new cookie from X if it runs with [X extension SECURITY](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xextproto/security.html). Be aware that you already need access to already running X to get a new cookie:

```
xauth -f /home/USERNAME/.Xauthority generate $DISPLAY . trusted
```

---

Standard way: Create a cookie for option `-auth` before starting X with

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0
xauth -f $XAUTHORITY add $DISPLAY . $(mcookie)
```

---

> restarting Xorg with -auth “$HOME/.Xauthority”

Be careful; check if `$HOME/.Xauthority` already exists and is not empty; otherwise X runs without authentication protocol at all, and everyone can access it. Rather create a cookie yourself with `xauth`.

---

I am not sure what you want to accomplish; just be aware that allowing access for multiple users to the same X display is a security risc / privacy leak. X clients can spy on each other.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think the last paragraph of my question hints at the direction I'm thinking - to have the system provide access to specific users at boot time (or login time?). For example, have some system file (say /etc/Xaccess) specify a list of users/groups (via their cookies?), and enable access for them at boot/login time. Any idea if there is a mechanism for this, or a straightforward way to do it?

Comment: A follow-up question. Regarding your 'standard way' -- where exactly does this happen? Do I replace the lightdm startup with this? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: A year later I've come back to this to realize that I overlooked your second solution - or at least misunderstood it originally. I do notice that lightdm creates a new :0 cookie on every boot, which means I do have to modify the start sequence to copy the new cookie to valid users. Where is the best place to do this?